# Amazon Redshift: query execution hangs

Tags: grails, hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I use amazon redshift and sometimes the query execution hangs without any error messages e.g.
this query will execute:

```
select extract(year from date), extract(week from date),count(*) from some_table  where date>'2015-01-01 00:00:00' and date<'2015-12-31 23:59:59' group by extract(year from date), extract(week from date)
```

and this not:

```
select extract(year from date), extract(week from date),count(*) from some_table  where date>'2014-01-01 00:00:00' and date<'2014-12-27 23:59:59' group by extract(year from date), extract(week from date)
```

But it happens only when I deploy project to server and on my local machine all queries executed without any problems.

I already set in my code `autoCommit=true` for connection.
Also all things listed above I do with grails using this library

```
        compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-redshift:1.9.39'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might not be an exact answer, but it's too long for a comment.

You may want to check `mtu` setting on the server where you performing the execution.

Redshift want's to operate on `1500` bytes frame and all EC2 instances are set with jumbo frame by default (`9000`)

In order for you to run queries without problems you need to have the same `mtu` setting.

To check what you currently have, run this command:

`ip addr show eth0`

an example output would be like this:

`eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000`

in this case mtu is 9001 so you need to change it to 1500 by running:

`/sbin/ifconfig eth0 mtu 1500 up`

Comment: yes, on my local machine mtu=1500 and on server=9001, seems like you was right.

Answer (score 4):

I was experiencing this issue when connecting to RedShift from an EC2 Instance. Adjusting the MTU didn't help, so I kept digging and found that the error is linked to TCP timeouts.

Doing the following in the instance that I was using to connect to RedShift fixed the problem:

```
# echo 60 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time
```

That will change the TCP keepalive from 7200 seconds (default) to 60 seconds.

More information can be found in:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-firewall-guidance.html